# (Object doesn't support #inspect)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-1.9.2

I have a simple case, involving two model classes:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :snapshots

  def initialize(params={})
   # ...
  end
end

class Snapshot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game

  def initialize(params={})
  # ...
  end
end
```

with these migrations:

```
class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :difficulty
      t.string :status

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateSnapshots < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :snapshots do |t|
      t.integer :game_id
      t.integer :branch_mark
      t.string  :previous_state
      t.integer :new_row
      t.integer :new_column
      t.integer :new_value

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

If I attempt to create a Snapshot instance in rails console, using

```
Snapshot.new
```

I get

```
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

Now for the good part.  If I comment out the initialize method in snapshot.rb, then  Snapshot.new works.  Why is this happening?
BTW I am using Rails 3.1, and Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: Although it may not have been your issue, this comes up when there's an error raised in a custom `inspect` method. The original error is not visible, which can be annoying.

Answer (score 10):

This is happening because you override the `initialize` method of your base class (ActiveRecord::Base). Instance variables defined in your base class will not get initialized and `#inspect` will fail.

To fix this problem you need to call `super` in your sub class:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :snapshots

  def initialize(params={})
   super(params)
   # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Why are you passing params to super? What would ActiveRecord::Base do with it?

Answer (score 8):

I had this symptom when I had a serialize in a model like this;

```
serialize :column1, :column2
```

Needs to be like;

```
serialize :column1
serialize :column2
```

Comment: and I wrote `serialize :description, Array` inproperly (as `serialize :description, :array`)

Comment: I had a similar issue when I was improperly serializing a `jsonb` column using `HashSerializer` with calls `to_json`. I managed to put string JSON into the jsonb column, which messed up Rails reading the data back out.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue when I used an invalid association name in a `joins`.

For example,

```
Book.joins(:authors).first
```

Should be

```
Book.joins(:author).first
```

Assuming a Book model `belongs_to` an Author model.

Answer (score 3):

This can also happen when you implement `after_initialize`, particularly if you are attempting to access attributes which were not included in your `select`.  For instance:

```
after_initialize do |pet|
  pet.speak_method ||= bark  # default
end
```

To fix, add a test for whether the attribute exists:

```
after_initialize do |pet|
  pet.speak_method ||= bark if pet.attributes.include? 'speak_method'  # default`
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly why, but I got this error when I accidentally misspelled 'belongs_to' as 'belong_to' in the associated class definition.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you forgot to

```html
rails db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling .valid? on the new object to see if you can get a more helpful error.

In my case, I got this error from a block of code that creates a new instance of one of my models and assigns values to its fields.  It turns out that my code was assigning a value to one of the fields that Rails couldn't match with that field's type.  Calling valid? on the new object gave me a more helpful error (undefined method `to_f' for #<MatchData...).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem after trying to integrate devise authentication with an existing User model, I solved it by running command below:

```
spring stop
```

Don't know the exact cause but hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This is a misleading and nonspecific error. For instance, I just got it because I made a scope like this:

```rb
scope :posted, -> { where('posted_on_date <= ?', Date.today) }
```

when it should have been:

```
scope :posted, -> { where('post_on_date <= ?', Date.today) }
```

In my case, this was due to my mistakenly using the `posted_on_date` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem if the model contains an `after_find`.

Answer (score 0):

The same error if you put the attribute type wrong:

```
attribute :publicar, :integer, default: true
```

instead of

```
attribute :publicar, :boolean, default: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when running an ActiveRecord `.where` clause/method.

It was simply because there was a **typo in the column name**. Once I fixed the typo the query worked exactly as expected.

Wrong:

```
Package.where(scrape_nunber: 2)
```

Right (fixed typo in column name, and it works now):

```
Package.where(scrape_number: 2)
```

Just double check there isn't a typo in your column name(s) in the where clause.