# Object doesn't support #inspect in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.0 app I've upgraded to 3.1. When I go to Rails console and run User.first I get this output...

```
irb(main):001:0> User.first
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  SHOW search_path
  User Indexes (1.0ms)   SELECT distinct i.relname, d.indisunique, d.indkey, t.oid
 FROM pg_class t
 INNER JOIN pg_index d ON t.oid = d.indrelid
 INNER JOIN pg_class i ON d.indexrelid = i.oid
 WHERE i.relkind = 'i'
 AND d.indisprimary = 'f'
 AND t.relname = 'users'
 AND i.relnamespace IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname IN ('"$user"','public') )
 ORDER BY i.relname

  User Indexes (0.4ms)   SELECT c2.relname, i.indisunique, pg_catalog.pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid, 0, true)
 FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c, pg_catalog.pg_class c2, pg_catalog.pg_index i
 WHERE c.relname = 'users'
 AND c.oid = i.indrelid AND i.indexrelid = c2.oid
 AND i.indisprimary = 'f'
 AND i.indexprs IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY 1

(Object doesn't support #inspect)
=>
irb(main):002:0> exit
```

ruby version:
ruby 1.9.3p-551

I know their are records in the database but I can't figure out what this error means?

(Object doesn't support #inspect)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does your `User` model has `first` method defined? (method override)

Comment: @DeepeshKakani `first` should be apart of Rails 3.1 itself no?

Comment: Yes but my question is does your model overrides it due to some reason?

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: Seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7690697/125816

Comment: @DeepeshKakani Ah I see. No. There is no method override for `first`

Comment: @rmlockerd version 1.9.3p551

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was a strange one and may not solve the entire problem just yet. As it turns out I had to turn on autoload paths for my /lib directory

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # startup the lib directory goodies
    config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
    config.autoload_paths += %W( lib/ )
```

This now resolves the `(Object doesn't support #inspect)` error message

HOWEVER...

A new error message of `undefined local variable or method acts_as_userstamp for #<Class:0x000000046bef50>` appears.

This method appears in the second line of my user model...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_userstamp
...
```

And that method is defined in a file called `app/lib/model_modificationsrb` located in my /lib directory

So now i must travel the rabbit hole deeper and find why that method is not being seen. I'll post a question regarding this new finding on a new question page.